# environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

I want to ask newbie question about environment variables in ubuntu

I'm trying to configure maven3 using `/etc/environment`. I installed maven manually i.e. unpacked, moved to `/opt/maven`.

My /etc/environment file

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_31"
JRE_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre"
MAVEN_HOME="/opt/maven"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$MAVEN_HOME/bin"
```

When I replace in `PATH` `$MAVEN_HOME` with `/opt/maven` everything works. If I revert changes -> maven is not installed. Why? I check maven after logout/login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/environment` is not a shell script. It is read by the [pam_env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/pam_env.8.html) module during log in, and it doesn't do variable expansions, it only accepts KEY=VALUE pairs. You could instead edit `/etc/profile` (which is a shell script), and add

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```